# Terraform run plan without AWS credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I wish to run a terraform plan to verify a terraform plan file uploaded by a user and detect the resources.

However, running terraform plan as of now requires AWS credentials.

Is there a way to run plan without using the credentials or extract the list of resources in another way from the .tf file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found a solution here,

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/5584#issuecomment-433203543

Along with the skip_credentials_validation flag, a mock secret_key is also required.

```
provider "aws" {
  region                      = "${var.region}"
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_requesting_account_id  = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
  s3_force_path_style         = true
  access_key                  = "mock_access_key"
  secret_key                  = "mock_secret_key"

}
```

Comment: Good, although it says "Error: AuthFailure: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials..."