# Terraform complains lack of AWS credentials in CICD Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, kubernetes-helm, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have a Terraform GitLab runner I've provisioned in my kubernetes cluster via Helm to execute Terraform related CICD pipelines. The runner users a specific service account that has access to a provisioned IAM Role for the runner using [IAM  Role for Service Accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html). To ensure that the runner is able to obtain the correct role, in my pipeline, I've included `aws sts get-caller-identity` call in my job and the job successfully returns the role. However, when `terraform plan -out=tfplan` or `terraform apply tfplan` is executed, I get the following error:

> Error: error configuring S3 Backend: no valid credential sources for
> S3 Backend found. │  │ Please see
> https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html │ for
> more information about providing credentials. │  │ Error:
> NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated. │     For
> verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors

This error comes up randomly. It does not occur consistently.

I've considered using "skip_credentials_validation" and "skip_requesting_account_id" as mentioned in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54269578/terraform-run-plan-without-aws-credentials), but I feel there should be a better way for terraform to detect if the credentials are present for this type of scenario without having to do this type of bypass or actually committing a credentials file into the repository with access key and secret access key to assume a role.

Does anyone know how this can be done such that terraform would pick up the role consistently without hardcoding credentials?

Comment: Could you post your backend configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that after upgrading the values.yml file for the GitLab Runner and upgrading the runner to be on the current version (15.2.1) combined with [IAM Role for Service Accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html) enabled terraform init and plan to run as expected.

Keep in mind I've also updated GitLab server to v15.3 as well such that it is generally in sync with the runner version.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try explicitly initialize terraform with your backend config?

```
terraform init \
  -backend-config="access_key=<your access key>" \
  -backend-config="secret_key=<your secret key>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. While this is part of [Terraform's documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/configuration#command-line-key-value-pairs), there are 2 downsides to using this method. 1) You will need to inject these keys in a safe manner (ie: ENV vars in CICD pipeline, which will still be accessible to anyone with elevated privileges in GitLab). 2) You will need to rotate the the keys from time to time to maintain good security posture. This solution will not be scalable as the number of Terraform GitLab Runners increase.

Comment: I understand, but I could not come to another solution since I don’t know if your tf code is correct. Take a look at this post with best practices to avoid authentication issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73758453/7950592